# SPARQL query with filter for a certain date

Tags: filter, sparql, jena, fuseki

I'm new to SPARQL and I'm trying to do the following thing for my assignment:

I need to pull out actors but only those that were born on a defined date. My problem is that every time I try to filter by a certain integer value, I get "Error making the query, see cause for details" (btw, I have no idea what "cause" is in this matter, there is no error log, or anything clickable for me to actually check what went wrong).

Here is my query:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX movie: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?actor ?dbpediaLink ?name ?date month(?date) WHERE {
        ?actor a movie:actor .
        ?actor owl:sameAs ?dbpediaLink .
    SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
        ?dbpediaLink dbpprop:name ?name .
        ?dbpediaLink dbpprop:dateOfBirth ?date
    }
    FILTER(month(?date) = 2)
}
LIMIT 10
```

So, what I'm trying to do here is get all actors born in February, and with this I get the error mentioned above.

The following combinations of `FILTER` return the mentioned error:

```
FILTER(month(?date) = 2)
FILTER(month(?date) > 1 && month(?date) < 3)
FILTER(month(?date) >= 2 && month(?date) <=2)
```

Basically all the variations for getting back only people born in February return the error. I even tried casting the integers explicitly as `"2"^^xsd:integer` (because the `month()` function returns an integer) and it still failed.

I also tried (for some other problem) to get actors that have exactly 10 letters in their name but I also ran into the same problem.

It seems that any `FILTER` I try to make that uses `=` or tries to `FILTER` by multiple conditions (using `&&`) fails.

I'm stuck on this for the last 2 days...Am I missing something?

I should probably mention that I'm using locally deployed Fuseki server with LMDB dump, and I'm running the queries at http://localhost:3030

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with your query has invalid syntax in it, you can't put `month(?date)` directly in your `SELECT` clause as you must enclose in it parentheses - `(` and `)` - and alias it using `AS`, e.g. --

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX movie: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?actor ?dbpediaLink ?name ?date (month(?date) AS ?month) WHERE {
        ?actor a movie:actor .
        ?actor owl:sameAs ?dbpediaLink .
    SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
        ?dbpediaLink dbpprop:name ?name .
        ?dbpediaLink dbpprop:dateOfBirth ?date
    }
    FILTER(month(?date) = 2)
}
LIMIT 10
```

The "cause" referred to is the exception that led to the exception shown to you.   If you are using code to submit the query, catch the exception, and check the `getCause()` method to see if there is another exception object.

Note that if you are using a standard Fuseki setup there may be more error information logged to the terminal window in which you started the Fuseki server (or wherever you redirected that server processes output to).

The problem is unlikely to be the filter, since a `FILTER` is defined by the SPARQL specification to treat any errors in expression evaluation as a `false`.

If the problem is not just your bad syntax, then the most likely culprit is the `SERVICE` clause in your query which is asking Fuseki to go and query some information from `http://dbpedia.org/sparql`.  `SERVICE` is defined such that if contacting the remote service fails, then the whole query fails.  So it is likely you are not able to access that service from your machine, or there is an error on the DBPedia end causing the problem (which is not unheard of).

Can you browse to that URL in your browser?  If you can, are you able to successfully run the portion of your query that appears in the `SERVICE` clause using the web interface there?

Note that you can add the `SILENT` keyword after the `SERVICE` keyword which will cause the query engine to continue even if the remote service request fails, e.g. --

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX movie: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?actor ?dbpediaLink ?name ?date month(?date) WHERE {
        ?actor a movie:actor .
        ?actor owl:sameAs ?dbpediaLink .
    SERVICE SILENT <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
        ?dbpediaLink dbpprop:name ?name .
        ?dbpediaLink dbpprop:dateOfBirth ?date
    }
    FILTER(month(?date) = 2)
}
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you very much, adding  `SILENT` fixed my problem, although I'm not sure why. If the request to dbpedia failed, how did I get the dates that are used in the `FILTER` ? The result I got was just what I needed, 10 actors that were born in February.

Comment: @mercin - Your addition of `SILENT` may have appeared to be the fix, but rather just coincided with some other change (perhaps DBpedia was restarted, or a network glitch was fixed, etc.)...